# Copying executable using CMake add_custom_command in visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, cmake

Some context: I'm compiling a legacy **CMake project** using Visual Studio 2019 on a Windows 10 host, but targeting a remote **aarch64 Ubuntu16.04 machine**. To do so, I added a debug configuration for "Linux-Debug" to point at the machine's IP address (this part works, as I can build, and debug with breakpoints).

The Problem:
I have the following **add_custom_command** inside my CMakeLists.txt

```
# Create the executable
add_executable( imageCaptureAEv1 ${SOURCES})

#copy it to the home directory
add_custom_command(TARGET imageCaptureAEv1 POST_BUILD
                   COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy $<TARGET_FILE:imageCaptureAEv1> /home/nvidia)
```

Where **/home/nvidia** is the directory I want to copy the executable to after I build it (POST_BUILD), and **imageCaptureAEv1** is the name of the executable.

I believe this copy never happens, as the file never shows up in /home/nvidia when I ssh into the Ubuntu machine. All I want to do is copy the executable to an easier to find directory (visual studio prepends the build directory with a crazy long hash that I could get rid of, but I'd rather keep the build directory separate from where I'm copying it).

Is there an easier way? Or, am I missing something with my command?

Comment: Use `add_custom_target` with `ALL` signature that depends on your command. This would make the command run during `ALL_BUILD` target.

Comment: @arrowd: With `POST_BUILD` the command specified in `add_custom_command` is run every time the target's output file is changed. So the current code in the question is correct too.

Comment: @arrowd I think your answer was correct also, but I found out that my executable just wasn't being overwritten on the target machine, so there wasn't an issue with the cmake code. Marking as resolved. Thanks folks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above cmake code DOES copy the executable, I just need to make sure a run a rebuild or clean then build in my particular environment, otherwise the executable doesn't get overwritten.